# How do I save a forwarded message as a TXT file in Outlook 2010?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, forwarding

Okay, one of my colleagues forwarded a message to me.  Outlook 2010 treats the forwarded message as an attachment.  I want to save the forwarded message to a TXT file.

If I use File > Save As from the parent message, I can save to a TXT file, but the attachment is omitted.

If I right click the attachment and select Save As, it only lets me save in Microsoft's crappy binary MSG format.

I checked the raw headers (File > Info > Properties > Internet Headers) in the hopes that those would contain the message, but they don't -- they're headers only, and only for the parent message, not the attachment.

I could copy and paste the text of the attachment, but I really need to see the headers of the attached message -- it's a bounce message, and I need to see what's in it to debug our email server.

Is there really no way to get the full source of a forwarded message in Outlook 2010?  Or am I just not seeing it?

Comment: If you open the attachment, can you do a File save as?

Comment: Alas, no; but see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally worked it out.  The trick is:

1. Right click the attachment.
2. Select "Save  As" and save it in the crappy Microsoft MSG format.
3. Open the .msg file in Outlook, which now treats it as an independent message.
4. Click the File tab, do "Save As".
5. Save it in TXT format.

It's a kludgy workaround, but it gets the job done.

Big shout out to Microsoft here for making a simple task insanely frustrating.  Well done.